# How to clear markers from leaflet map added by drawToolbar?

Tags: r, r-leaflet

How can I clear markers that have been added via `drawToolbar` on `leaflet` map in `shiny`? If you add a marker and then click the `actionButton`, the marker remains on the map. Is this a bug? I tried both `clearMarkers` and `clearGroup` but neither worked.

```
library(shiny)  
library(leaflet)
library(leaflet.extras)

ui <- fluidPage(
  leafletOutput("map"),
  actionButton("rm", "Remove markers")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$map <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet()  %>% 
      addTiles() %>% 
      addDrawToolbar(targetGroup = "x")
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$rm, {
    leafletProxy('map') %>%
      clearMarkers() %>%
      clearGroup("x")
  })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 2):

The toolbar is part of the `output$map` object created at the beginning.  To remove it, you'll need to assign a new value to `output$map` that doesn't contain the toolbar.  For example,

```
library(shiny)  
library(leaflet)
library(leaflet.extras)

ui <- fluidPage(
  leafletOutput("map"),
  actionButton("rm", "Remove markers")
)
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  toolbar <- TRUE
  init <- function() renderLeaflet({
    leaf <- leaflet()  %>% addTiles()
    if (toolbar)
      leaf <- leaf %>% 
        addDrawToolbar(targetGroup = "x")
    leaf
  })
  
  output$map <- init()
  
  observeEvent(input$rm, {
    toolbar <<- !toolbar
    output$map <- init()
    leafletProxy('map') %>%
      clearMarkers() %>%
      clearGroup("x")
  })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

You should be able to call `removeDrawToolbar()` to get rid of it, but there is a bug in that code, with some workarounds listed:  https://github.com/bhaskarvk/leaflet.extras/issues/148

Comment: Thanks, actually I do not want to remove the drawToolbar, only the  markers added with the toolbar, see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I came up with:

```
library(shiny)  
library(leaflet)
library(leaflet.extras)

ui <- fluidPage(
  leafletOutput("map"),
  actionButton("rm", "Remove markers")
)
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  init <- function() {
    renderLeaflet({
      leaf <- 
        leaflet() %>% 
        addTiles() %>% 
        addDrawToolbar() 
      
      bounds <- isolate({input$map_bounds})
      if (!is.null(bounds)) {
        center <- c("lat" = mean(c(bounds$north, bounds$south)),
                    "lng" = mean(c(bounds$east, bounds$west)))
        
        leaf <- 
          leaf %>% 
          setView(lng = center[["lng"]],
                  lat = center[["lat"]],
                  zoom = isolate({input$map_zoom}))
      }
      
      leaf
    })
  }
  
  output$map <- init()
  
  observeEvent(input$rm, {
    output$map <- init()
  })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

It redraws the map on `actionButton` click (thanks to @user2554330 for the idea). If there is a solution without redrawing the map, e.g. with the `clearMarkers()` function, I would be interested.